# Different ways to reload or restart Firewalld

Tags: firewalld

To reload firewalld I [could use](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye-backports/firewalld/firewall-cmd.1.en.html#Status_Options):

- `firewall-cmd --reload` or
- `firewall-cmd --complete-reload`

How do those differ from:

- `systemctl reload firewalld` and
- `systemctl restart firewalld`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that technically they do the same.

It depends on how long the Init.d system will stay on a specific distribution, as I remember systemd will be the "successor" of it.